# Same pixel per inch image for texture painting no matter of the size of the images

Tags: texture-painting, resolution

I'm wondering if there is an option that make texture mapping image(for texture painting) the same ppi(pixels per inches) no matter the size of the texture image.

I run into a problem where smaller meshes(furnitures) got better resolution than big ones(field).

Is there a way to scale images to meshes and keep the same resolution?

Comment: Probably this can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR3Y9R2wmdI